# static library, get access to self.view

Tags: ios, uikit, static-libraries

i'm working on a static library, where i need to have access to self.view 
i'm trying to give the caller a reference to self.view by letting him pass it as a parameter

in the header file the .h

```
- (void) myM:(UIView *)myView;
```

but this is giving me an error:

> expected a type

please can anyone help,

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to import the UIKit headers. Add this at the top of your header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a forward declaration to your header:

```
@class UIView;
```

if you need to use the view, add this to your .m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```